# When do I need to impose 'static trait bound on a generic type

Tags: rust, static, lifetime

It happens right, left and center that the rust compiler requests to add some overlooked trait bounds on a generic type. Nothing to shout about.

Yet I happened to try to figure out why I was suggested to add the `'static` **trait bound**. Since the program is too complex I tried to jot down something concise which would model the program behaviour on a small scale. Still, I've failed to come up with such a pet program which would require to impose `'static` trait bound on a generic type.

I can state that the big program in question requires `'static` trait bounds on types which are sent through `tokio::sync::mpsc`/`broadcast` channels and for some generics wrapped in `Arc<T: Send + Sync + 'static>`.

Yet I cannot reproduce the need of `'static` on a small scale program. I guess some one might furnish me with such an example where on top of `Send + Sync` I would have to stick to `'static` type as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple really whenever something with a static context uses your generic parameter it has get the lifetime bound `'static`:

```rust
fn needs_static<T: Send + 'static>(r: T) {
    // requires `T: 'static` because it takes a `FnOnce() -> T + 'static`
    std::thread::spawn(move || r);
}

fn doesnt_need_static<T: Send>(r: T) {
    //doesn't require static because there is no such bound on s.spawn
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(move || r);
    });
}
```

Or in other words lifetime bounds work the exact same as trait bounds, the compiler suggests them when it detects they are needed.

Comment: No wonder if I somewhere require `'static` in the interface of a function I face the need of it trying to call it somewhere else. But my question is more about why I would need for `'static` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You should nearly never need to specify the `'static` trait bound in your own functions unless it's allowing values to escape unusually, such as with `mpsc` and `spawn` like you mentioned. Those are situations where rust can't statically check that references are valid. Internally, these usually put the value into a leaked `Box` (as a pointer) or a static variable, which both need `'static` values to be usable and sound.

In normal code, a reference can only escape a function by giving it to a function parameter or by returning it, which are exactly what rust's borrow rules check.

There's some situations where values appear to escape the function but don't need `'static`, which will involve some check outside of the borrow checker to ensure soundness. This is how `std::thread::scope` works, which you can see [transmuting a short lifetime to `'static` here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3a8a131e9509c478ece1c58fe0ea2d49463d2300/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs#L561) in order to bypass the borrow rules and use the regular `std::thread::spawn` internally. This is made sound by the fact that the only way to interact with the `std::thread::Scope` type is through the `std::thread::scope` function, which uses those same borrow rules to ensure `Scope` doesn't escape.